# Update variable in python after each loop

Tags: python, loops, variables, assign

Been struggling with this for a little while, I want the variable "result" to be updated after each loop of the function so that next time it steps through the function it will return something new. I have tried assigning result outside of my function then attempting to update it like that but haven't had any look.

```
def move2(msg):
    global result
    if result is None:
        print "Error result variable does not have a value"
    elif result is "rtn":
        rtn()
        result = "fwd"
        return result
    elif result is "fwd":
        fwd()
        result = "step"
        return result
    elif result is "step":
        step()
        result = "rtn"
        return result
    else:
        print "ERROR"
```

To note I am fairly new to python and am not opposed to other approaches if any of you have suggestions. Thanks

Comment: For all practical purposes, just pass `result` as an argument to `move2()`.

Comment: What's the (purposed) use to `rospy.sleep(3)` after the `return` statement, btw? Those calls will never be executed.

Comment: just added in code i forgot to take out just ignore it

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to make your function stateful which is generally a bad idea. Make it a class instead, like

```
from itertools import cycle

class StatefulCaller:
    def __init__(self, state_fns, repeat=True):
        if repeat:
            state_fns = cycle(state_fns)
        self.fn_iter = iter(state_fns)
    def __call__(self):
        return next(self.fn_iter)()
```

which you can then use like:

```
rtn  = lambda: "rtn"
fwd  = lambda: "fwd"
step = lambda: "step"

myfn = StatefulCaller([rtn, fwd, step])

for i in range(10):
    print(i, myfn())
```

which results in

```
0 rtn
1 fwd
2 step
3 rtn
4 fwd
5 step
6 rtn
7 fwd
8 step
9 rtn
```

Comment: Nice solution. But maybe a bit too advanced  for the formulation of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this could work:

```
def move2(msg, result=None):

    if result is None:
        print "Error result variable does not have a value"
    elif result is "rtn":
        rtn()
        result = "fwd"
        return result
    elif result is "fwd":
        fwd()
        result = "step"
        return result
    elif result is "step":
        step()
        result = "rtn"
        return result
    else:
        print "ERROR"
    return result
```

First call:

```
result = move2('Hello', 'start result')
```

Next call:

```
result = move2('Hello again', result)
```

**Note**: You don't do anything with `msg`. Either remove it as argument or use inside the function.

Comment: Thanks I am just heading out but i will try this as soon as I get back. See if it helps :)

Comment: You should do the comaprison with `==`, not with `is`.

Comment: @Matthias [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says: *Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with is or is not , never the equality operators.*×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes